# Compare time stamps in Excel?

Tags: excel, formatting, timestamp, excel-formula

I have an issue with excel and would need an solution preferably without having to use VBA code.

My excel document has two sheets:

- Rawdata sheet: contains data; column A has content in timestamp format `(dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss)`
- Calculations sheet: uses `countif()` and `sumif()` formulas

Now I have a set of date parameters in my calculation sheet, also formatted with the timestamp format as seen above. I now want to use those parameters in my formulas as conditions, for example:

```
    countif(Rawdata!A:A;">=Parameter1";Rawdata!A:A;"<Parameter2")
```

Although I have data that fits those parameters only 0 is displayed.

Is there any problem with the syntax of the formular itself or is the issue caused by errors concerning the formatting of the date parameters/ data??

Comment: what is Parameter1 and 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `Parameter1` and `Parameter2` are named ranges you need to separate the content form the literal String

```
countif(Rawdata!A:A;">=" & Parameter1;Rawdata!A:A;"<" & Parameter2)
```